# Cannot access remote SQL server 2012 from C# code in VS2013 after installing SQL server 2012 and setting up related configuration for firewall

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, firewall

In order to clarify my specific problem and add additional details to highlight exactly what I need, I rephrase my previous question.

I need to access a remote SQL server 2012 (version 11) from C# Visual Studio 2013 on my laptop win7.

My connection string is

```
 string MyConnectString = "Data Source=SQLServerName;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myId;Password=Mypassword";

 using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(MyConnectString))
 {
     conn.Open(); // **got error here.**
 }
```

The **error**:

```
  A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a 
 connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
 Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is   
 configured  to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, 
 error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

I have searched some possible solutions at:

```
   http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331> 
   http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ (try to resolve the connect string)
   https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2340/resolving-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-errors/
  http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/03/11/resolving-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server/
  http://www.technologycrowds.com/2014/02/could-not-open-connection-to-sql-server.html
  http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/335874/A-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occur
   http://www.mcbsys.com/blog/2012/12/connect-to-sql-server-2012-express-over-the-network/
```

**None** of them worked for me.

I have **installed SQL server 2012** from 
     http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23691
on my laptop.

In SQL server 2012 config manager, I have **enabled TCP/IP SQL server browser and named pipes** in SQL server network configuration. The **all instances** of SQL server: MSSQL11 which is the downloaded SQL server 2012 and SQLEXPRESS (it has been installed in my laptop by default) are all "**Running**".

I have checked the **firewall**, and created a new inbound and outbound rule for port 1433 for public, private and domain.

Also, in VS2013, tools --> add **database**, I can connect the remote SQL server by running "test connection" with the same ID and password used in the connection string.  But, in VS2013, tools --> add **server**, I **cannot** add the remote SQL server. I got **error**:

```
 **Cannot** **reconnect** to the remote server, make sure the path and machine name are valid.
```

Why it is "reconnect" ?  I have **never** connected it successfully.

I have also **restarted** my laptop after setting all of them.

But, I still cannot access the remote SQL server from C# code.

But, I **can access a remote SQL server 2008** from the same C# code with the same connect string (just replace the server name and database  name) on my laptop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can clearly connect to the database, so your ports arent the issue. Which leads me to think the problem is simply in your connection string. Something cant be quite right

Comment: have you attempted to connect to a local db on the same machine, and if you have were there any problems?

Comment: @Takarii, I can use the same string to access a remote SQL server 2008. I do not have a local DB on my laptop.

Comment: is there a specific reason for the `Persist Security Info` property being set to true? generally its left at false or no

Comment: @Takarii, this is the reason:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bb97cafd-d3aa-450a-ad33-f8e450c8a7b3/persist-security-info. I got the same error if I set it to false.

Comment: when you connected using the VS add database feature, did you replicate your connection string flags in the advanced section?

Comment: can you show me your fill connection string (just replace the actual words with something random)

Comment: Have you enabled mixed authentication mode on the SQL Server as you are using a SQL Server login?

Comment: @Takarii, This is the real connect string: "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myLogInID;Password=Mypassword"

Comment: @Takarii, in VS add database feature, my connection string flags in the advanced section are what I expect.

Comment: @Matt, when I logged into the server from management studio, I used "SQL server Authentication",

Comment: @user3750163 the 'User ID' should be 'User Id'

Comment: @Matt, I changed it, but still got the same error.